# How do I recursively plot centroids of a given set of points?

Tags: python, plot, drawing, polygon, draw

Say I have an n no of points with known coordinates. I want to write code which progressively plots the centroids of all possible combinations of these points and then repeats the same using all the points (including the centroids previously plotted).

However I have no idea of what libraries in python I should use or how, or if even python is best language for something of this sort. I am open to learning any other language if it suits the purpose better.

I am interested in seeing how the figure evolves given different initial points (vertices of polygons mainly).

Edit: By recursively, I mean that starting with n points, I get <sup>n</sup>C<sub>3</sub> centroids. next I will use n + <sup>n</sup>C<sub>3</sub> points as my initial points to find out the next set of centroids

Comment: By 'plot', do you mean using matplotlib(actually _drawing_ the triangle and plotting the point) or only finding coordinates of centroid of the triangle?

Comment: I want to see the points on the screen. I don't know how I can do it frrom matplotlib, or if i can do it.

Comment: Ok. Also, can you explain what do you mean by plotting them recursively? Does it mean that you want to use a recursive function for achieving that?

Comment: edited the question, please see.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code which will plot the points *"recursively"*, with the given *accuracy*. For `accuracy = 1`, it plots coordinates of all the centroids of the points. For `accuracy = 2`, it plots coordinates of all the centroids of the points and the centroids of the centroids of the points, and so on...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import combinations

def centroids(prev_centroid, coordinates, accuracy):
    if accuracy == 0:
        return list(set([tuple(ti) for ti in prev_centroid]))    
    centroid_list = []
    for point1, point2, point3 in combinations(coordinates, 3):
        x = (point1[0] + point2[0] + point3[0])/3
        y = (point1[1] + point2[1] + point3[1])/3
        centroid_list.append([x, y])       
    prev_centroid += centroid_list
    return centroids(prev_centroid, centroid_list, accuracy-1)


coordinates = *your_coordinates*
accuracy = *your_accuracy*
prev_centroid = []

coordinates_to_plot = centroids(prev_centroid, coordinates, accuracy)

xcoordinates = []
ycoordinates = []    
for a in coordinates_to_plot:
    xcoordinates.append(a[0])
    ycoordinates.append(a[1])    
plt.plot([xcoordinates], [ycoordinates], "o")
plt.show()
```

**Note:** You must have installed *matplotlib* and *itertools* libraries for this code.

**Explanation of code:**

```
def centroids(prev_centroid, coordinates, accuracy):
    if accuracy == 0:
        return list(set([tuple(ti) for ti in prev_centroid]))    
    centroid_list = []
    for point1, point2, point3 in combinations(coordinates, 3):
        x = (point1[0] + point2[0] + point3[0])/3
        y = (point1[1] + point2[1] + point3[1])/3
        centroid_list.append([x, y])       
    return centroids(prev_centroid + centroid_list, centroid_list, accuracy-1)
```

This is the most important function of the program, an it takes 2 lists (`prev_centroid`, `coordinates`) and an integer (`accuracy`). It uses all the coordinates to calculate their respective centroids and all the coordinates are appended into a list named `centroid_list`. Then it again calls the function centroids() *recursively* and calls `accuracy` as `previous_accuracy_minus_1`, and `prev_centroid` as `prev_centroid + centroid_list`, and `coordinates` as `centroid_list` as we want to take these coordinates of centroids as initial coordinates for the next calculation of centroids. Also, we have put the condition in this function that if `accuracy` becomes zero, then the function essentially stops.

Comment: If the answer is good enough and upto the mark, then please accept it. 